# Column Name Ambiguously Defined

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select entity_id, post_date, trade_date, settlement_date, local_currency, issue_name, primary_asset_id, 
alt_asset_id, trans_type, gl_account, linked_event_id, update_source, update_date, Exception_Reason, cancel_acctg_date, trans_type, src_intfc_inst 
from
(select c.entity_id, c.post_date, c.trade_date, c.settlement_date, c.local_currency, sm.issue_name, sm.primary_asset_id, 
sm.alt_asset_id, c.trans_type, c.gl_account, c.linked_event_id, c.update_source, c.update_date,
case when c.gl_account not in ('ADMIN FEES',
'AUDIT FEES',
'CURRENT CAPITAL CONTRIBUTIONS',
'COUPON ADJUSTMENTS',
'CASH ADJUSTMENTS-IN','CASH ADJUSTMENTS-OUT',
'CUSTODY FEES',
'CURRENT CAPITAL WITHDRAWALS',
'DIVIDEND ADJUSTMENTS',
'DAILY VARIATION MARGIN',
'INTERNAL FUND TRANSFER-IN','INTERNAL FUND TRANSFER-OUT',
'MARGIN DEPOSITS',
'MANAGEMENT FEES',
'MARGIN WITHDRAWALS',
'NDF FIXING ADJUSTMENTS ',
'OTHER FEES',
'TRAILER FEE REBATE',
'ROC ADJUSTMENTS ',
'CURRENT CAPITAL REDEMPTIONS',
'CURRENT CAPITAL SUBSCRIPTIONS',
'WITHHOLDING TAX') then 'Out_Scope_Transaction_Type' end as Exception_Reason, c.cancel_acctg_date, c.trans_type, c.src_intfc_inst
from cashdbo.cash_activity c
inner join securitydbo.security_master sm on sm.security_alias = c.security_alias
where c.gl_account not in ('ADMIN FEES',
'AUDIT FEES',
'CURRENT CAPITAL CONTRIBUTIONS',
'COUPON ADJUSTMENTS',
'CASH ADJUSTMENTS-IN','CASH ADJUSTMENTS-OUT',
'CUSTODY FEES',
'CURRENT CAPITAL WITHDRAWALS',
'DIVIDEND ADJUSTMENTS',
'DAILY VARIATION MARGIN',
'INTERNAL FUND TRANSFER-IN','INTERNAL FUND TRANSFER-OUT',
'MARGIN DEPOSITS',
'MANAGEMENT FEES',
'MARGIN WITHDRAWALS',
'NDF FIXING ADJUSTMENTS ',
'OTHER FEES',
'TRAILER FEE REBATE',
'ROC ADJUSTMENTS ',
'CURRENT CAPITAL REDEMPTIONS',
'CURRENT CAPITAL SUBSCRIPTIONS',
'WITHHOLDING TAX')
union all
select c.entity_id, c.post_date, c.trade_date, c.settlement_date, c.local_currency, sm.issue_name, sm.primary_asset_id, 
sm.alt_asset_id, c.trans_type, c.gl_account, c.linked_event_id, c.update_source, c.update_date,
'Missing Security ID' as Exception_Reason, c.cancel_acctg_date, c.trans_type, c.src_intfc_inst
from cashdbo.cash_activity c
inner join securitydbo.security_master sm on sm.security_Alias = c.security_alias
where (c.gl_account in ('COUPON ADJUSTMENTS',
'DIVIDEND ADJUSTMENTS',
'DAILY VARIATION MARGIN',
'MANAGEMENT FEES',
'NDF FIXING ADJUSTMENTS ',
'ROC ADJUSTMENTS ',
'WITHHOLDING TAX')
and ((sm.primary_asset_id is null) or (sm.alt_asset_id is null)))
union all
select c.entity_id, c.post_date, c.trade_date, c.settlement_date, c.local_currency, sm.issue_name, sm.primary_asset_id, 
sm.alt_asset_id, c.trans_type, c.gl_account, c.linked_event_id, c.update_source, c.update_date,
'Income Category' as Exception_Reason, c.cancel_acctg_date, c.trans_type, c.src_intfc_inst
from cashdbo.cash_activity c
inner join securitydbo.security_master sm on sm.security_Alias = c.security_alias
where c.trade_date != c.settlement_date
and c.gl_account in ('COUPON ADJUSTMENTS',
'DIVIDEND ADJUSTMENTS',
'DAILY VARIATION MARGIN',
'NDF FIXING ADJUSTMENTS ',
'WITHHOLDING TAX'))
where trunc (post_date) = ('22-Jan-2020') --trunc (sysdate -1)
AND cancel_acctg_date IS NULL 
AND trans_type NOT LIKE '%$%' 
and src_intfc_inst = 17
```

Comment: Please [edit] your code so that it is not left-justified and does not go over the right-margin so that we can read it. Someone might be willing to read through your code in its current format but unless you put some effort in to making it easy for people to help you it is unlikely that you are going to get as much assistance as you otherwise could.

Comment: That error message means somewhere in the projection your union subquery has two different columns **with the same name** or maybe **the same column selected twice**. Either way you need to find those two columns and give one of them an alias or de-select it as necessary. Perhaps some kind soul will do the hard work for you but your code is not easy to read. Proper layout enhances readability and **readability is a feature**.

Comment: I've reformatted the code, however because the post is entirely code I am unable to submit the changes as an edit - "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

I think the only way around this is to add some superfluous text which does not add anything additional to the question, but this doesn't sit well with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `C.TRANS_TYPE` twice in the inner query.

Remove one of them and it will work fine.

Cheers!!